# Unable to send a mail using JavaMail api

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I'm trying to sned a mail using the below code :-

```
java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(
                new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        new SwingWorker<Void, Integer>() {

                            String to = "xx@gmail.com";
                            // Sender's email ID needs to be mentioned
                            String from = "xexx@gmail.com";
                            // Assuming you are sending email from localhost
                            String host = "localhost";
                            // Get system properties
                         //   Properties properties = System.getProperties();

                            // Setup mail server


                            protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
                                try {
Properties properties =  new Properties();
properties.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
properties.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class","javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        // Get the default Session object.
        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);

                                    // Create a default MimeMessage object.
                                    MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);

                                    // Set From: header field of the header.
                                    message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));

                                    // Set To: header field of the header.
                                    message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                                            new InternetAddress(to));

                                    // Set Subject: header field
                                    message.setSubject("This is the Subject Line!");

                                    // Now set the actual message
                                    message.setText("Message" + jTextField1.getText() + " xx " + jTextField2.getText());

                                    // Send message
                                    Transport.send(message);

                                } catch (Exception x) {
                                    x.printStackTrace();
                                }
                                return null;
                            }

                            protected void process() {

                            }

                            protected void done() {
                                try {

                                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You'll get a response from our team shortly !");

                                } catch (Exception x) {
                                }

                            }
                        }.execute();
                    }
```

On call of the above code i'm getting an Exception :

```
javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: localhost, port: 25;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.SocketException: Permission denied: connect
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1934)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:638)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:295)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:176)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:125)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:194)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)
    at ims.Activation$5$1.doInBackground(Activation.java:374)
    at ims.Activation$5$1.doInBackground(Activation.java:327)
    at javax.swing.SwingWorker$1.call(SwingWorker.java:296)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at javax.swing.SwingWorker.run(SwingWorker.java:335)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Permission denied: connect
    at java.net.TwoStacksPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:157)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:391)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.createSocket(SocketFetcher.java:288)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.getSocket(SocketFetcher.java:231)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1900)
    ... 15 more
```

How can i resolve this?

Comment: Is your local machine set up as a valid `SMTP` host?

Comment: @c.pramod are you using JDK 7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you are running a mail server on your local environment, then you are going to need to specify one via additional mail properties:

```
properties.put("mail.smtp.host", aHost);
```

As an example, if you were using the Gmail relay, you would have:

```
properties.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
```

In addition you need the `mail.smtp.auth` property setup for the session.

```
properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", true);
```

Depending on which host you end up using, you will probably also need to supply authentication information. For example, again with the Gmail relay:

```
Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props,
    new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return new PasswordAuthentication("someUserName", "somePassword");
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: did exactly the same . Now i'm getting com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 530-5.5.1 Authentication Required.  Exception

Comment: @c.pramod - you actually need to supply valid credentials (I assume you're using the Gmail relay?). Fill in your account username and password where shown in the example.

Comment: i added this line properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
and it worked .. Thx for the reply BTW !!

Comment: Edited answer to include the missing property, and np. Good luck with the rest of the project.