# Error while executing jar file

Tags: java, netbeans, jar

I'm trying to run a jar file which sends a mail, using this command:

```
java -jar sendmail.jar
```

When I run the code from NetBeans everything works fine, but when I export to a jar file and run the jar file I get the following error:

```
Error Sending mailjavax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host:
 smtp.<xxx>.com, port: 25;
  nested exception is:
        java.net.SocketException: Permission denied: connect
```

After I got the error I executed the code from NetBeans, and the mail was sent. Thus I don't have any issue with SMTP or connection.

I think that the jar file cannot locate the mail.jar.
Please advise.

Comment: have you set proper classpath for your jar?

Comment: If you created `.jar` from netbeans then you don't have to worry about supporting `mail.jar` file. It copy supported `.jar` file in lib folder next to your `.jar` file.

Comment: If it runs fine in netbeans and not after build then it must be some kind of import not included into the jar file..

Comment: maybe a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15484940/unable-to-send-a-mail-using-javamail-api

Comment: How you are creating `.jar` file?

Comment: @Abu - yes class path is properly set.

Comment: @VickyThakor - i just clean and build the project

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8360913/weird-java-net-socketexception-permission-denied-connect-error-when-running-groo

Comment: Is there any chance that you are using different JVMs in NetBeans and in console to run jar? There are known issue with JDK7: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12902187/1430055

Comment: @MaksimKolesnikov -  i think this may be the issue.
i see that the jvm on netbeans is 1.6.
and on console is 1.7.how to change it to 1.7 on netbeans?

Comment: In Netbeans, right click on the project > properties > Libraries and choose a JDK 7 Java Platform. After that you'll see this error both in console and in NetBeans. To fix it you should explicitly define VM option `-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does your machine by any chance use ipv6? if it does, you can try to start your jar with the `-Djava.net.preferIPV4Stack=true` argument.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that the mail.jar is probably imported under the libs and your not just referenced it.

Comment: the mail.jar is indeed under the libs

Comment: Try to remove then add it again.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to put your mail.jar file into lib folder and also ensure that your lib folder and sendmail.jar files are present in same directory.